# Chrome F8/hotkey debugger breaking during a drag and drop operation

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, drag-and-drop, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's web-developer tools one can break at any point by pressing `F8`.

Often times I would like to break and inspect an element during a drag and drop operation by pressing F8. This won't work however.

Is there a native Chrome-way shortcut without running a custom script?

Comment: I have reported this bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=637252).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, devtools window has to be focused in order for keyboard shortcuts to work. While you're dragging an element, it is the dragged element that has the focus, not the devtools window. The best you can do is with a custom script.

Try setting a timeout in the console to trigger the debugger after 2s:

```
setTimeout(function(){debugger;}, 2000);
```

And then step out of that function.

Comment: You can create a bookmark that when clicked will pause after 2 seconds. Create a new bookmark, then set `javascript:(function(){setTimeout(function(){debugger;}, 2000);})();` as the url

Answer (score 15):

> Is there a native Chrome-way shortcut without running a custom script?

No. Without any extra steps the DevTools must be in focus for <kbd>F8</kbd> to pause execution.

---

If you'd like to call `debugger` while DevTools is open but *not* in focus, you can attach an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the <kbd>F8</kbd> key in a couple ways. These will work when you are dragging an element and you want to pause script execution.

**1)** Open the console and manually run this script on the target site before debugging:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){ if(e.key === 'F8') {debugger;} }, false);
```

This will attach an event listener for the <kbd>F8</kbd> key which will trigger `debugger`.

**2)** Create a userscript for [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) which runs the above script on sites that you permit. Sample userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         F8 to debug
// @version      0.1
// @description  Press F8 when the console is open to trigger 'debugger'
// @author       Drakes
// @grant        none
// @require      none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log("Press F8 when the console is open to trigger 'debugger'");
function KeyCheck(e) {
    if(e.key === 'F8') {
        debugger;
    }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyCheck, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used something similar so far, but might potentially interfere with debugging as it directly affects the event listeners in the context to be debugged. So I will take your second point to heart where the context should differ.

Comment: Agreed, however, when you pass in "false" to event listener, it doesn't capture the event. Also, by adding the event listener using `addEventListener` it adds the listener to a chain of listeners (not overwriting any), and hopefully none will fire logic on F8 too :)

Comment: nice, this is much better than the timeout solution, and does what I think everyone that lands here needs: makes F8 work when you're focused on the DOM. Can't believe this is still a problem 5 years later.

Comment: This helped me a lot, way better than the timeout solution.  Thank you!

Comment: It's beautiful...

Answer (score 5):

I do have a better solution without changing anything on the code.
Below trick is valid on **Chrome Webtools**, and for others I haven't checked.

### Steps to put debug on drag and drop or even on any event of your choice

1. Open Dev Tools, jump to the sources tab, and check out the Event Listener Breakpoints
2. You would see Drag / drop event! but before going further. Stop there. If we use this, we’ll get a breakpoint on the very moment a drag/drop event is called. We don’t really want that right
3. we want to pause the UI state at a moment of my choosing, perhaps while dragging over a particular element. So instead of drag/drop, check the Keyboard event box.
   [image: Chrome Webtools Event Listeners]
4. Now, drag whatever you like, and at the appropriate moment hit any key from the keyboard.
5. Finally we got one paused state. You can’t right click to inspect elements, but you can use the element selector tool - hit the button top left of the Dev Tools pane,  or [Cmd/Ctrl] + [Shift] + [C] and point at the element you want to inspect.

> NOTE: Don’t forget to uncheck the Event Listener Breakpoint when you
> are done

Comment: This didn't work for me. Do we need to have an actual keyboard event listener in the source, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Open dev tools and click f8 -> Open Dev Tools, jump to the sources tab, and check out the Event Listener Breakpoints -> click keyboard checkbox, something like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rin7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This seems to be a duplicate of an [existing answer from March 8, 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66529564/666583). Please [edit] your answer to provide information that is substantially distinct from existing answers.